# Proof of Brun's theorem

Tags: number-theory

I am looking for a proof of Brun's theorem about the convergence of the sum of reciprocal twin primes.

It would be great to have something rather "self-contained" - so that somebody with thorough background in mathematics but without special knowledge about (analytical) number theory can understand it.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423125/confusing-proof-of-bruns-theorem). The comments refer to Tenenbaum's book. It has a self-contained proof. Also Prachar's book has a very detailed proof. Also, see [problemsolving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Brun%27s_constant).

Comment: Here is something else that might be useful. It appears as an exercise in http://people.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/M229.18/sieve.pdf